# Why npm doesn't let me to install any package individually in windows 11?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I just switched to `windows 11` but there's something weird going on.Each time I attempt to install any npm package which throws me error like below.(Angular project created from scratch in this example via ng new command).

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! electron@21.2.1 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@21.2.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Timuçin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-01T15_25_24_552Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Timuçin\Documents\Projects\demo-proj>
```

I attempted to install electron via running `npm i electron` which thrown me error like above

Also tried some other packages to install via `npm install` but always fails.

I played around current `angular`,`node`(used `LTS` also) and `npm` versions but nothing did work.So since only `OS` changed from `win10` to `win11` I think win11 is problem here but why and how?Please help me.

Version Details

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.7
Node: 14.15.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.9
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.7
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.7
@angular/cli                    14.2.7
@schematics/angular             14.2.7
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Comment: try deliting `node_modules` then `package-lock.json`  run `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install`

Comment: @Woohaik did all but didn't work